# How to return a value from an EventEmitter function?

Tags: angular

I got this function in my `core` component:

```js
 isValid(value: any) {

   // Do some stuff and return something based on the result

   return false;
 }
```

Which I pass to the `other-component` like this:

```
<other-component (onBeforeAdding)="isValid($event)"></other-component>
```

And in `other-component` I got this `EventEmitter` function which should run before other things and return a value stating that a value is valid or not:

```js
 @Output() onBeforeAdding: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 let isValid = this.onBeforeAdding.emit(value) || true;

 if (isValid) {

   // Do stuff
 }
```

The problem here is that an `EventEmitter` function can't return a value since it's asynchronous (although from rc2 it seems that this is optional by passing true to the `new EventEmitter` function? Even doing so won't fix this issue however). So `isValid` will always be true regardless of what the function returns.

How can I return a value from the `EventEmitter` function?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do this with `@Output`, but you can do something very similar with `@Input`.

Same function in `core` component:

```js
isValid(value: any): boolean {
  // Do some stuff and return something based on the result
  return false;
}
```

Pass the function definition in to `other-component` as an `@Input`:

```xml
<other-component [onBeforeAddingProcessor]="isValid"></other-component>
```

In `other-component`:

```js
@Input() onBeforeAddingProcessor: (value: any) => boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  // onBeforeAddingProcessor won't be defined in the constructor
  let isValid = this.onBeforeAddingProcessor(value);

  if (isValid) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

### Methods accessing `this`

If you have to access `this` in the function you provide, then it's necessary to pass a method which already has the this-context bound:

```js
isValid = (value: any) => {
  return this.myService.checkValue(value);
}
```

Otherwise Angular calls the method with `this` of the component, not the consumer of the component.
Small hint regarding performance (though not tested): if this method is large and the instance-count of the component is high, then you should factor out the bigger parts of the code to a private member function and call this function from where it was factored out. Reason: Above does not create a function on the prototype of the class, but stamps out a copy of this function for each instance of the component. This can consume a lot of memory which can be avoided easily.

Comment: Love it when the first few sentences of a stack overflow answer works for me, and when an unrelated issue arises, the same answer even anticipates and answers that issue; thank @hgoebl for "If you have to access this in the function you provide". I do! `this` has the service I'll call!

Comment: ... and in reading the answer to the issue, I learn something new (of course implied in hgoebl's edit); that lambdas aka "fat arrows" [will bind `this` so it can't be changed.](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Comment: Also, this is a great way to use `@Input` instead of `@Output` when you need the returned value on the child component.

Comment: @TheRedPea, I believe the lambda (fat arrows) work because they create a closure which locks in the variable in the lexical environment.

Comment: I am getting error at below line "Cannot find name value" in the line 

let isValid = this.onBeforeAddingProcessor(value);

How to access this.onBeforeAddingProcessor??

Comment: @Anna in his example `value`is never declared, you gotta declare your own value variable.

Comment: @TheRedPea if it hadn't been for your second comment I wouldn't have noticed the damned definition of isValid as an arrow function!

Answer (score 4):

You need to subscribe on the event emitter to get the value:

```js
this.onBeforeAdding.emit(value || true);

this.onBeforeAdding.subscribe(isValid => {
  if (isValid) {
    // Do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: [Ward Bell: Do Not Expect EventEmitter To Be Observable In Angular 2](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3045-ward-bell-do-not-expect-eventemitter-to-be-observable-in-angular-2.htm) Not sure what should we expect.

Comment: I have to run the function which calls the onBeforeAdding twice before the subscribe method runs. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes agreed it's only for component outputs. Seems to be the case here ;-)

Comment: Also how do you return the value form the isValid function? Because isValid becomes the value now, rather than the value I return from isValid, which should be false.

Comment: I'd actually need both the boolean and the value in the subcribe.

Comment: You could emit an object instead: this.onBeforeAdding.emit({ value, valid });

Comment: Yes, the problem though is that I don't want the value from the emitter, I want the value form the function that runs when you emit.

Comment: That is what I thought. I don't think this answer help your case. like I said EventEmitter is one way street. It doesn't provide the feature you want

Comment: I had same problem and I tried this solution. This is not working and you can't subscribe for `EventEmitter` response.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible without much effort

1. Create EventEmitter within your child component

```
@Output('request_data')
requestData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

2. create a method to request data within your child component, the trick here is to pass an object with an anonymous function

```
    click() {
        this.requestData.emit({
            data: "some-data",
            func: (data_from_parent => {
               //do whatever you want
            })
        });
    }
```

3. From your parent component, do whatever you want and call the function

```
     callFromChild(obj) {
        //obj.data
        //obj.func();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Child
this.yourFunction.emit({func:(data_form_parent)=>{console.log(data_form_parent)}})

//Parent
yourFunction($event) {
 const {func}= $event;
 func('this data will return to your child')
}
```