# Child component calls a method in Parent component AND return a value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-next

**Parent**

**HTML**

```
 <tr  
    [onTotalWeights]="totalWeights"
  >
```

**Code**

```
totalWeights(): number { 
   return // Get sum of fields over the whole array
  }
```

**Child**

```
  @Input() onTotalWeights: () => number;

   canApplyChanges() {
     return this.onTotalWeights() <= 100 && this.form.valid;
  }
```

I want to call a method on the parent from the child and return a value.

The problem at the moment is that in the child the this.onTotalWeights() when it is called the "this" keyword refers to the methods/variables inside the child component and not from the parent component. Somehow the context is lost when I passed down the totalWeights function.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal JS behavior. You can customize it by calling `.bind()`

```
totalWeights(): number { ... }

totalWeightsFn = this.totalWeights.bind(this);
```

```
[onTotalWeights]="totalWeightsFn"
```

Comment: I also thought of using bind but I have read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102948/how-to-return-a-value-from-an-eventemitter-function this solution mentions the lost context, but does not provide a bind solution to the context problem or I do not see it...

Comment: It uses arrow function. Using arrow function `() => {}` is another way of accomplishing the same. For passing closures, arrow functions are usually more convenient, for passing function references `.bind()` is usually more convenient because it doesn't required to repeat the parameters like `someObject.someCallback((x)  => this.foo(x))` instead of `someObject.someCallbacl(this.foo.bind(this))`.