# Passing down callback function to chid gives "ERROR TypeError: <func> is not a function"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass down a callback function to my `app-autocomplete` component. For that there is a `displayFn` input parameter:

```xml
<app-autocomplete [displayFn]="displayWith" formControlName="starter">
</app-autocomplete>
```

where the parent component implements just

```
displayWith(item) {
  return item ? item.name : null;
}
```

The `app-autocomplete` component itself has a `mat-autocomplete` component where the `[displayWith]` function gets wrappey by `onSelectEvent`:

```xml
<mat-autocomplete [displayWith]="onSelectEvent" #autocomplete="matAutocomplete">
</mat-autocomplete>
```

All `onSelectEvent` does/is suppsed to do is saving the selected option and then call the passed `displayFn`:

```
onSelectEvent(option) {
  this.selectedOption = option;
  return this.displayFn(option);
}
```

However, I am getting

> `ERROR TypeError: this.displayFn is not a function`

and I don't understand why. What am I doing different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981813/826983)?

It's the same error for

```
onSelectEvent = (option) => {
  this.selectedOption = option;
  return this.displayFn(option);
}
```

---

Here is the entire component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  styles: [`
  `],
  template: `
  <div class="app-autocomplete">

    <mat-form-field>
      <input #autocompleteInput matInput
             [placeholder]="placeholder" autocomplete="off" [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete"/>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-icon-button type="button" [disabled]="disabled">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="onSelectEvent" autoActiveFirstOption>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>    
  </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutocompleteComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AutocompleteComponent),
      multi: true,
    }]
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

  @ViewChild('autocompleteInput')
  autocompleteInput: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  options = [];

  @Input()
  placeholder;

  @Input()
  displayFn: (value: any) => string;

  disabled;

  selectedOption;
  filteredOptions$;

  _onChangeCallback = (value: any) => {};
  _onTouchedCallback = () => {};


  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions$ = of(this.options);
  }

  filterOptions(v) {

  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.value = obj.value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this._onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {

  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | any {
    return undefined;
  }

  onSelectEvent = (option) => {
    this.selectedOption = option;
    return this.displayFn(option);
  }

}
```

Comment: Try `displayWith = function(item){  // Do something }`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the same as the question you linked to. You are accessing `this` in non-arrow function which is undefined in `mat-autocomplete` component's context.

Your `onSelectEvent` should be arrow function:

```
onSelectEvent = (option) => {
    this.selectedOption = option;
    return this.displayFn(option);
}
```

I have created [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9iwqss). First button uses non arrow function and fails same way as your code. Second button uses arrow function and correctly calls the input function.

Comment: `this.selectedOption = option` will always work because `this` is always available, but it might be not what you expect. It is not setting `selectedOption` in `app-autocomplete` but in `mat-autocomplete`. Try debugging in `onSelectEvent` and inspect `this`.

Comment: yeah, now I see what you mean. `this` points at an instance ot `MatAutocomplete` - makes sense. The question now is how I'll work around this ^^

Comment: well, the arrow function should help, `this` should be `app-autocomplete`

Comment: Hm, no. `this` is still a `MatAutocomplete` O_o. That's what I got: `onSelectEvent = (option) => {
    this.selectedOption = option;
    return this.displayFn(option);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

`this.displayFn` should be EventEmitter for `app-autocomplete` component. if `onSelectEvent` function is written inside `app-autocomplete` then below code will work for you.

```
onSelectEvent(option) {
    this.selectedOption = option;
    return this.displayFn.emit(option);
}
```

Comment: For some reason `this` is not a reference to `app-autocomplete`. I've updated my question with the entire code of the component.

Comment: make it non-arrow function, i am updating my post well,

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was just doing it totally wrong. It took me surprisingly long to realize that there is also a `onSelectionChange` for `mat-option` - but to be fair there is [no example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) currently. It is mention [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) though.

So I am passing `onSelectionChange`

```xml
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange(option)" >
  {{option.name}}
</mat-option>
```

which stores the selection:

```
onSelectionChange(option) {
  this.selectedOption = option;
}
```

Now I can just pass `displayFn` to `displayWith`:

```xml
<mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" autoActiveFirstOption>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

which now may come from anywhere and does not require a reference to a `app-autocomplete` component:

```
displayWith(option) {
  return option ? option.name : null;
}
```